# Magento attributes showing in one theme / not showing in another

Tags: magento, layered-navigation

Magento attributes not showing in layered navigation.
In my original Theme attributes are showing as they should.
When use another theme,  all attributes are not showing.
Obviously there must be somewhere in the theme but I do not know where to change it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is very short on details about what you're actually dealing with. Please consider giving more details, or deleting your question. Thanks.

Comment: Have you set 'Is Anchor' to true or yes on the category? Under admin -> Manage Categories

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess your situation with so few information, but if your 'original theme' contains some extra code for attributes in layered navigation, then the file should be in

```
\app\design\frontend\PACKAGE\THEME\template\catalog\navigation\left.phtml
```